# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I found an error of QuerySet object has no attribute 'email'.. i tried my best to solve the problem but don't able to find a solution..

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from loginsystem.models import newUser
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned

 def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        try:
            userdetails=newUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])
            print("username=", userdetails)
            request.session['email']=userdetails.email
            return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 6):

add `.first()` in your userdetails:

```
userdetails=newUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password']).first()
```

the filter is return `QuerySet[]`. the `get_object_or_404` is return Instance, so you have to use `.first()` to get the user in `QuerySet[]`, or use `get_object_or_404`.

Comment: Please Explain why!

Answer (score 3):

**use "get" instead of "filter".**

**filter**: return multiple objects.
**get**: return a single object. you are accessing email with userdetails.email so, userdetails must be a single object.

```
 def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        try:
            userdetails=newUser.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])
            print("username=", userdetails)
            request.session['email']=userdetails.email
            return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: Explain why pls!

Comment: filter: return multiple objects.
get: return a single object.

you are accessing email with userdetails.email so, userdetails must be a single object.

Comment: Thank. Can you add that to your answer. If you do I will upvote it :-)

Comment: @ShaidHasanShawon Sir i use `.get` instead of `.filter` but it shows MultipleObjectsReturned at /login.

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned:
it means the email you are getting from request.POST['email'] is not unique in newUser model. you have multiple users with the same email.
it will better if you make your email model filed unique=True.

before doing unique=True this.
go to dajngo admin panel and remove all the repeated emails to unique otherwise, you will get migrations error.

Comment: @ShaidHasanShawon Sir again same error occurs.. But i used `userdetails=newUser.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])` this and get required result... Sir basically i am new on django so don't know much about django or programing or coding... Thanks Sir for your guide... I am grateful to you for help

Answer (score 2):

The filter method returns a list(i.e. Queryset) instead of a unique value as that which you intend. You should use the get method instead

```
userdetails=newUser.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])
```

or

```
userdetails=newUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])[0]
```

NB: getting non unique queries, i.e. multiple object will raise the  `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception. Be sure to get indexed objects.
if you are not sure the object is unique, do

```
userdetails=newUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'] , password=request.POST['password'])
if userdetails.exists():
    userdetails = userdetails[0]
```

Comment: Add something about the case of multiple objects with get!